# Union vs. static_cast(void*)

Tags: c++, void-pointers, static-cast, unions

I'm writing code and until now I was using structures like this:

```
struct s{
  enum Types { zero = 0, one, two };
  unsigned int type;
  void* data;
}
```

I needed some generic structure to store data from different classes and I wanted to use it in std::vector, so that's reason why I can't use templates. What's better option: unions or void pointers?

Void pointer allocates only as much space as I need, but c++ is strong typed language for some reason and casting everywhere I need to use those data is not the way c++ code should be designed. As I read, void pointers shouldn't be used unless there's no alternative.

That alternative could be Unions. They comes with c++ and uses the same memory space for every member, very much like void pointers. However they come at price - allocated space is the size of largest element in union, and in my case differences between sizes are big.

This is rather stylistic and "correct language using" problem, as both ways accomplish what I need to do, but I can't decide if nicely stylized c++ code can pay for that wasted memory (even though memory these days isn't a big concern).

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html ?

Comment: If you wan't non-strict type checking while maintaining safety maybe c++ isn't the language to the job. take a look at C#.

Comment: You _can_ use templates. Just create a base class with the required interface and store pointers.

Comment: @Dani I'm writting cross-platform portable code + it takes many functions from another c++ library so C# is not a choice. (not mentioning porting whole code to C# would cause me to abandon project)

Comment: You are just adding your own type system on top of the existing one. What is the advantage?

Comment: @Raven: just a point: you can call C# from C++ and C++ from C# and its portable, take a look on mono http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Comment: @Dani That's good to know, I always thought of C# as windows only thing. I think I'll look then into C# in future. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html) or [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html) if you want to store objects of heterogeneous types.

And before deciding which one to use, have a look at the comparison:

- [Boost.Variant vs. Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/variant/misc.html#variant.versus-any)

Hopefully, it will help you to make the correct decision. Choose one, and any of the container from the standard library to store the objects, `std::vector<boost::any>`,  `std::vector<boost::variant>`, or any other.

Comment: +1 boost::any is what I need. However I was fine until now without boost libraries and as this project is going to be just another library, I don't look forward to making dependency to such huge library just for one feature. Anyway it's great to know that such things exist and I definitely make use of them in my project. Thanks

Comment: @Raven:  Note that both Boost.Any and Boost.Variant are header-only libraries, so there is no runtime dependency.  (Besides, once you start using boost, you'll probably find plenty of other features you'll want to use.)

Comment: @Sevis That's the reason I couldn't locate any runtime libraries, thanks for poiting out that for me! Changed my view on thing once again -> Remarking right answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Basically, it is a type-safe union, and in this case, it seems like unions are by far the most appropriate answer.  A `void*` could be used, but that would mean dynamic allocation, and you would have to maintain the `Types` `enum`, and the table for casting.

Memory constraints could make `void*` an acceptable choice, but it's not the 'neat' answer, and I wouldn't go for it until both `boost::variant` and just a plain `union` have shown to be unacceptable.

Comment: +1 for stating that unions are more suitable(as matched with boost:variant)

Answer (score 1):

If your classes have enough in common to be put in the same container give them a base class with a virtual destructor, and possibly a virtual member function to retrieve your type code, even though at that point not only dynamic_cast would be more appropriate, but it could be reasonable to explore whether your classes don't have enough in common to provide them with a more complete common interface.

Otherwise consider providing a custom container class with appropriately typed data members to hold instances of all the different classes you need to put into it.

Comment: +1 Actually one place where I used void pointer was suitable for using interface class.. looks much better after edit!