# container of unrelated T in c++

Tags: c++, generics, containers

If I have the following hypothetical class:

```
namespace System
{
    template <class T>
    class Container
    {
    public:
        Container() { }
        ~Container() { }
    }
}
```

If I instantiate two Containers with different T's, say:

```
Container<int> a;
Container<string> b;
```

I would like to create vector with pointers to a and b. Since a and b are different types, normally this wouldn't be possible. However, if I did something like:

```
std::stack<void*> _collection;
void *p = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&a);
void *q = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&b);
_collection.push(a);
_collection.push(b);
```

Then later on, I can get a and b back from _collection like so:

```
Container<string> b = *reinterpret_cast<Container<string>*>(_collection.pop());
Container<int> a = *reinterpret_cast<Container<int>*>(_collection.pop());
```

My question is, is this the best way for storing a collection of unrelated types? Also would this be the preferred way of storing and retrieving the pointers from the vector (the reinterpret cast)? I've looked around and seen that boost has a nicer way of solving this, Boost::Any, but since this is a learning project I am on I would like to do it myself (Also I have been curious to find a good reason to use a reinterpret_cast correctly).

Comment: I don't think there is ever (or almost ever) a good reason for `reinterpret_cast` and this whole project feels like a huge smell. :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I store objects of differing types in a C++ container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738405/how-can-i-store-objects-of-differing-types-in-a-c-container)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is possible to cast to `void *` and back, the problem is knowing which type you're popping. After all, you give the example:

```
Container<string> b = *reinterpret_cast<Container<string>*>(_collection.pop());
Container<int> a = *reinterpret_cast<Container<int>*>(_collection.pop());
```

However, if you were to accidentally do:

```
Container<int> a = *reinterpret_cast<Container<int>*>(_collection.pop());
Container<string> b = *reinterpret_cast<Container<string>*>(_collection.pop());
```

Now you've got pointers to the wrong type, and will likely see crashes - or worse.

If you want to do something like this, *at least* use `dynamic_cast` to check that you have the right types. With `dynamic_cast`, you can have C++ check, at runtime (using [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information)), that your cast is safe, as long as the types being casted (both before and after) have a common base type with at least one virtual method.

So, first create a common base type with a virtual destructor:

```
class ContainerBase {
public:
  virtual ~ContainerBase() { }
};
```

Make your containers derive from it:

```
template <typename T>
class Container : public ContainerBase {
// ...
}
```

Now use a `std::stack<ContainerBase *>`. When you retrieve items from the stack, use `dynamic_cast<Container<int> >(stack.pop())` or `dynamic_cast<Container<string> >(stack.pop())`; if you have the types wrong, these will check, and will return NULL.

That said, heterogeneous containers are almost always the wrong thing to be using; at some level you need to know what's in the container so you can actually *use* it. What are you actually trying to accomplish by creating a container like this?

Answer (score 6):

Consider [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html) or [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html) if you want to store objects of heterogeneous types.

And before deciding which one to use, have a look at the comparison:

- [Boost.Variant vs. Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/variant/misc.html#variant.versus-any)

Hopefully, it will help you to make the correct decision. Choose one, and any of the container from the standard library to store the objects, `std::stack<boost::any>`,  `std::stack<boost::variant>`, or any other. **Don't write your own container.**

I repeat **don't write your own container**. Use containers from the standard library. They're well-tested.

Comment: Do you have pre-made set of standard answers or how did you do that so fast? :)

Comment: @pmr: Such questions has been asked too many times : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132248/union-vs-static-castvoid/7132273#7132273

Comment: I know. But I still try to type up my own answer. Why not just vote to close this?

Comment: @pmr: I doubt if its exact duplicate, though if he knows the language well enough, then he can get his answer from other topic. But from his post, it seems that he is just a newbie and trying to explore the language, writing his own container of objects of heterogeneous types. So let him get more and different kind of response from different people.